# How to make select dropdown multiple select in bootstrap and angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

This is single select dropdown, I want to make it multiple select dropdown
I use **`multiple and class="custom-select"`** in select but it shows opened select menu but I want to display dropdown when I click on dropdown if possible help for checkbox type for multiple select dropdown menu in bootstrap and angularjs ?

```
Type:
<select class="form-control" ng-model="list.type">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Type</option>
   <option ng-repeat="types in listTypes" value="{{types.id}}">
      {{types.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not totally sure I understand what you are after. Adding the  ‘multiple’ attribute to the ‘select’ directive should be all you need to select multiple options from your list.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: @tbone849 it is displays opened dropdown but i want to open only when click on that

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same concern in my Project. And a little more features, that I wanted.**

**This Code has features like *Closed Dropdown menu, Checkbox for every option, a Search box to search for specified Option, Select ALL and UnSelect ALL.***

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="countriesData" selected-model="countriesModel" checkboxes="true" extra-settings="countriesSettings"></div>
    <pre>Selected Model: {{countriesModel}} | json</pre>
</div>
```

**Angular JS Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.countriesModel = [];
    $scope.countriesSettings = {
        scrollableHeight: '200px',
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true
    };
    $scope.countriesData = [{
        "label": "Connecticut",
            "id": "CT"
    }, {
        "label": "Delaware",
            "id": "DE"
    }, {
        "label": "District Of Columbia",
            "id": "DC"
    }, {
        "label": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
            "id": "FM"
    }, {
        "label": "Florida",
            "id": "FL"
    }, {
        "label": "Georgia",
            "id": "GA"
    }, {
        "label": "Idaho",
            "id": "ID"
    }, {
        "label": "Illinois",
            "id": "IL"
    }, {
        "label": "Kansas",
            "id": "KS"
    }, {
        "label": "Kentucky",
            "id": "KY"
    }, {
        "label": "Louisiana",
            "id": "LA"
    }, {
        "label": "Maine",
            "id": "ME"
    }, {
        "label": "Minnesota",
            "id": "MN"
    }, {
        "label": "Mississippi",
            "id": "MS"
    }, {
        "label": "Missouri",
            "id": "MO"
    }, {
        "label": "Nevada",
            "id": "NV"
    }, {
        "label": "New Hampshire",
            "id": "NH"
    }, {
        "label": "New Jersey",
            "id": "NJ"
    }, {
        "label": "New Mexico",
            "id": "NM"
    }, {
        "label": "New York",
            "id": "NY"
    }, {
        "label": "North Carolina",
            "id": "NC"
    }, {
        "label": "North Dakota",
            "id": "ND"
    }, {
        "label": "Northern Mariana Islands",
            "id": "MP"
    }, {
        "label": "Ohio",
            "id": "OH"
    }, {
        "label": "Oklahoma",
            "id": "OK"
    }, {
        "label": "Oregon",
            "id": "OR"
    }, {
        "label": "Palau",
            "id": "PW"
    }, {
        "label": "Pennsylvania",
            "id": "PA"
    }, {
        "label": "Puerto Rico",
            "id": "PR"
    }, {
        "label": "Rhode Island",
            "id": "RI"
    }, {
        "label": "South Carolina",
            "id": "SC"
    }, {
        "label": "South Dakota",
            "id": "SD"
    }, {
        "label": "Tennessee",
            "id": "TN"
    }, {
        "label": "Texas",
            "id": "TX"
    }, {
        "label": "Utah",
            "id": "UT"
    }, {
        "label": "Vermont",
            "id": "VT"
    }, {
        "label": "Virgin Islands",
            "id": "VI"
    }, {
        "label": "Virginia",
            "id": "VA"
    }, {
        "label": "Washington",
            "id": "WA"
    }, {
        "label": "West Virginia",
            "id": "WV"
    }, {
        "label": "Wisconsin",
            "id": "WI"
    }, {
        "label": "Wyoming",
            "id": "WY"
    }];
    $scope.example2settings = {
        displayProp: 'id'
    };
});

var directiveModule = angular.module('angularjs-dropdown-multiselect', []);

directiveModule.directive('ngDropdownMultiselect', ['$filter', '$document', '$compile', '$parse',

function ($filter, $document, $compile, $parse) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            selectedModel: '=',
            options: '=',
            extraSettings: '=',
            events: '=',
            searchFilter: '=?',
            translationTexts: '=',
            groupBy: '@'
        },
        template: function (element, attrs) {
            var checkboxes = attrs.checkboxes ? true : false;
            var groups = attrs.groupBy ? true : false;

            var template = '<div class="multiselect-parent btn-group dropdown-multiselect">';
            template += '<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-class="settings.buttonClasses" ng-click="toggleDropdown()">{{getButtonText()}}&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>';
            template += '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" ng-style="{display: open ? \'block\' : \'none\', height : settings.scrollable ? settings.scrollableHeight : \'auto\' }" style="overflow: scroll" >';
            template += '<li ng-hide="!settings.showCheckAll || settings.selectionLimit > 0"><a data-ng-click="selectAll()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  {{texts.checkAll}}</a>';
            template += '<li ng-show="settings.showUncheckAll"><a data-ng-click="deselectAll();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>   {{texts.uncheckAll}}</a></li>';
            template += '<li ng-hide="(!settings.showCheckAll || settings.selectionLimit > 0) && !settings.showUncheckAll" class="divider"></li>';
            template += '<li ng-show="settings.enableSearch"><div class="dropdown-header"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="searchFilter" placeholder="{{texts.searchPlaceholder}}" /></li>';
            template += '<li ng-show="settings.enableSearch" class="divider"></li>';

            if (groups) {
                template += '<li ng-repeat-start="option in orderedItems | filter: searchFilter" ng-show="getPropertyForObject(option, settings.groupBy) !== getPropertyForObject(orderedItems[$index - 1], settings.groupBy)" role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">{{ getGroupTitle(getPropertyForObject(option, settings.groupBy)) }}</li>';
                template += '<li ng-repeat-end role="presentation">';
            } else {
                template += '<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in options | filter: searchFilter">';
            }

            template += '<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="setSelectedItem(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))">';

            if (checkboxes) {
                template += '<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" ng-click="checkboxClick($event, getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))" ng-checked="isChecked(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))" /> {{getPropertyForObject(option, settings.displayProp)}}</label></div></a>';
            } else {
                template += '<span data-ng-class="{\'glyphicon glyphicon-ok\': isChecked(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))}"></span> {{getPropertyForObject(option, settings.displayProp)}}</a>';
            }

            template += '</li>';

            template += '<li class="divider" ng-show="settings.selectionLimit > 1"></li>';
            template += '<li role="presentation" ng-show="settings.selectionLimit > 1"><a role="menuitem">{{selectedModel.length}} {{texts.selectionOf}} {{settings.selectionLimit}} {{texts.selectionCount}}</a></li>';

            template += '</ul>';
            template += '</div>';

            element.html(template);
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var $dropdownTrigger = $element.children()[0];

            $scope.toggleDropdown = function () {
                $scope.open = !$scope.open;
            };

            $scope.checkboxClick = function ($event, id) {
                $scope.setSelectedItem(id);
                $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            };

            $scope.externalEvents = {
                onItemSelect: angular.noop,
                onItemDeselect: angular.noop,
                onSelectAll: angular.noop,
                onDeselectAll: angular.noop,
                onInitDone: angular.noop,
                onMaxSelectionReached: angular.noop
            };

            $scope.settings = {
                dynamicTitle: true,
                scrollable: false,
                scrollableHeight: '300px',
                closeOnBlur: true,
                displayProp: 'label',
                idProp: 'id',
                externalIdProp: 'id',
                enableSearch: false,
                selectionLimit: 0,
                showCheckAll: true,
                showUncheckAll: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
                buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default',
                closeOnDeselect: false,
                groupBy: $attrs.groupBy || undefined,
                groupByTextProvider: null,
                smartButtonMaxItems: 0,
                smartButtonTextConverter: angular.noop
            };

            $scope.texts = {
                checkAll: 'Check All',
                uncheckAll: 'Uncheck All',
                selectionCount: 'checked',
                selectionOf: '/',
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
                buttonDefaultText: 'Select',
                dynamicButtonTextSuffix: 'checked'
            };

            $scope.searchFilter = $scope.searchFilter || '';

            if (angular.isDefined($scope.settings.groupBy)) {
                $scope.$watch('options', function (newValue) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
                        $scope.orderedItems = $filter('orderBy')(newValue, $scope.settings.groupBy);
                    }
                });
            }

            angular.extend($scope.settings, $scope.extraSettings || []);
            angular.extend($scope.externalEvents, $scope.events || []);
            angular.extend($scope.texts, $scope.translationTexts);

            $scope.singleSelection = $scope.settings.selectionLimit === 1;

            function getFindObj(id) {
                var findObj = {};

                if ($scope.settings.externalIdProp === '') {
                    findObj[$scope.settings.idProp] = id;
                } else {
                    findObj[$scope.settings.externalIdProp] = id;
                }

                return findObj;
            }

            function clearObject(object) {
                for (var prop in object) {
                    delete object[prop];
                }
            }

            if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                if (angular.isArray($scope.selectedModel) && $scope.selectedModel.length === 0) {
                    clearObject($scope.selectedModel);
                }
            }

            if ($scope.settings.closeOnBlur) {
                $document.on('click', function (e) {
                    var target = e.target.parentElement;
                    var parentFound = false;

                    while (angular.isDefined(target) && target !== null && !parentFound) {
                        if (_.contains(target.className.split(' '), 'multiselect-parent') && !parentFound) {
                            if (target === $dropdownTrigger) {
                                parentFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                        target = target.parentElement;
                    }

                    if (!parentFound) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.open = false;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            $scope.getGroupTitle = function (groupValue) {
                if ($scope.settings.groupByTextProvider !== null) {
                    return $scope.settings.groupByTextProvider(groupValue);
                }

                return groupValue;
            };

            $scope.getButtonText = function () {
                if ($scope.settings.dynamicTitle && ($scope.selectedModel.length > 0 || (angular.isObject($scope.selectedModel) && _.keys($scope.selectedModel).length > 0))) {
                    if ($scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems > 0) {
                        var itemsText = [];

                        angular.forEach($scope.options, function (optionItem) {
                            if ($scope.isChecked($scope.getPropertyForObject(optionItem, $scope.settings.idProp))) {
                                var displayText = $scope.getPropertyForObject(optionItem, $scope.settings.displayProp);
                                var converterResponse = $scope.settings.smartButtonTextConverter(displayText, optionItem);

                                itemsText.push(converterResponse ? converterResponse : displayText);
                            }
                        });

                        if ($scope.selectedModel.length > $scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems) {
                            itemsText = itemsText.slice(0, $scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems);
                            itemsText.push('...');
                        }

                        return itemsText.join(', ');
                    } else {
                        var totalSelected;

                        if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                            totalSelected = ($scope.selectedModel !== null && angular.isDefined($scope.selectedModel[$scope.settings.idProp])) ? 1 : 0;
                        } else {
                            totalSelected = angular.isDefined($scope.selectedModel) ? $scope.selectedModel.length : 0;
                        }

                        if (totalSelected === 0) {
                            return $scope.texts.buttonDefaultText;
                        } else {
                            return totalSelected + ' ' + $scope.texts.dynamicButtonTextSuffix;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return $scope.texts.buttonDefaultText;
                }
            };

            $scope.getPropertyForObject = function (object, property) {
                if (angular.isDefined(object) && object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    return object[property];
                }

                return '';
            };

            $scope.selectAll = function () {
                $scope.deselectAll(false);
                $scope.externalEvents.onSelectAll();

                angular.forEach($scope.options, function (value) {
                    $scope.setSelectedItem(value[$scope.settings.idProp], true);
                });
            };

            $scope.deselectAll = function (sendEvent) {
                sendEvent = sendEvent || true;

                if (sendEvent) {
                    $scope.externalEvents.onDeselectAll();
                }

                if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                    clearObject($scope.selectedModel);
                } else {
                    $scope.selectedModel.splice(0, $scope.selectedModel.length);
                }
            };

            $scope.setSelectedItem = function (id, dontRemove) {
                var findObj = getFindObj(id);
                var finalObj = null;

                if ($scope.settings.externalIdProp === '') {
                    finalObj = _.find($scope.options, findObj);
                } else {
                    finalObj = findObj;
                }

                if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                    clearObject($scope.selectedModel);
                    angular.extend($scope.selectedModel, finalObj);
                    $scope.externalEvents.onItemSelect(finalObj);
                    if ($scope.settings.closeOnSelect) $scope.open = false;

                    return;
                }

                dontRemove = dontRemove || false;

                var exists = _.findIndex($scope.selectedModel, findObj) !== -1;

                if (!dontRemove && exists) {
                    $scope.selectedModel.splice(_.findIndex($scope.selectedModel, findObj), 1);
                    $scope.externalEvents.onItemDeselect(findObj);
                } else if (!exists && ($scope.settings.selectionLimit === 0 || $scope.selectedModel.length < $scope.settings.selectionLimit)) {
                    $scope.selectedModel.push(finalObj);
                    $scope.externalEvents.onItemSelect(finalObj);
                }
                if ($scope.settings.closeOnSelect) $scope.open = false;
            };

            $scope.isChecked = function (id) {
                if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                    return $scope.selectedModel !== null && angular.isDefined($scope.selectedModel[$scope.settings.idProp]) && $scope.selectedModel[$scope.settings.idProp] === getFindObj(id)[$scope.settings.idProp];
                }

                return _.findIndex($scope.selectedModel, getFindObj(id)) !== -1;
            };

            $scope.externalEvents.onInitDone();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

***Simple Version 2:***

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="multiselectddlController">
    <div style="font-weight: bold;">Get Selected Country</div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="country in SelectedCountries">
        <ul>
            <li>{{country.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <multiselect-dropdown model=" SelectedCountries " options="MasterCountries "></multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

**Angular JS Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('multiselectDropdown', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            options: '=',
        },
        template:
            "<div class='btn-group' data-ng-class='{open: open}' style='width: 200px;'>" +
            "<button class='btn btn-small' style='width: 160px;'>---Select---</button>" +
            "<button class='btn btn-small dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='openDropdown()' style='width: 40px;' ><span class='caret'></span></button>" +
            "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu' style='position: relative;'>" +
            "<li style='cursor:pointer;' data-ng-repeat='option in options'><a data-ng-click='toggleSelectItem(option)'><span data-ng-class='getClassName(option)' aria-hidden='true'></span> {{option.name}}</a></li>" +
            "</ul>" +
            "</div>",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.openDropdown = function () {
                $scope.open = !$scope.open;
            };
            $scope.selectAll = function () {
                $scope.model = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.options, function (item, index) {
                    $scope.model.push(item);
                });
            };
            $scope.deselectAll = function () {
                $scope.model = [];
            };
            $scope.toggleSelectItem = function (option) {
                var intIndex = -1;
                angular.forEach($scope.model, function (item, index) {
                    if (item.id == option.id) {
                        intIndex = index;
                    }
                });
                if (intIndex >= 0) {
                    $scope.model.splice(intIndex, 1);
                } else {
                    $scope.model.push(option);
                }
            };
            $scope.getClassName = function (option) {
                var varClassName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle';
                angular.forEach($scope.model, function (item, index) {
                    if (item.id == option.id) {
                        varClassName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle';
                    }
                });
                return (varClassName);
            };
        }
    }
});
app.controller("multiselectddlController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.SelectedCountries = [];
    $scope.MasterCountries = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "India"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "America"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Japan"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "China"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Germany"}
    ];
});
```